# apache poi so slow to read an xlsx file

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read in java(*using Apache POI*) an xlsx file, but it takes so much time... I don't know why it happens, I have already tried to increase a **JVM** heap but it doesn't work... The excel file has 28000 rows, but i don't read a sheet, It begins to be slow when I just create a workbook like that:

```
file = new FileInputStream(xlsxPath);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

What is the meter of this strange behaviour of Apache POI, maybe someone has already had this problem, what is the solution, thank you all for your help!!!

Comment: You probably need `SXSSF` instead...

Comment: But SXSSF is used only to write not to read exel shet data

Comment: Oh boy, I mixed it up. This is what you are looking for then.  http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api

Comment: Sorry, but from exel file which occupies less then 9 Mb, it loads in heap 1Gb, is it a normal behaviour of Apache POI?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use

```
  BufferedInputStream bfs = new BufferedInputStream
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(bfs);
```

Comment: yes, I have, but it still slow... may be this due to logging, how to disable this option?